# javascript blocks css code

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<p class='sent' id='abc'>abc</p>
<p class='sent' id='abb'>abb</p>
<p class='sent' id='acc'>acc</p>
```

css

```
.sent:hover{
background-color:#e1e1e1;  // works until the first click on .sent
}
```

js

```
$(".sent").click(function() {
$('.sent').css('background-color', 'transparent'); //works
$(this).css('background-color', '#e1e1e1');  //works
});
```

After first click on `sent` css `sent:hover` doesnt work !?

Comment: Because you've set the default colour to be the hover colour, so obviously there will be no visual change.

Comment: That's because you are setting an inline-style.

Comment: @danrhul I think there's multiple `.sent` elements, so he wants the current chosen **or** the hovering element to have colour `#e1e1e1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline styles have precedence over rules defined in style blocks.

Try removing the `background-color` style instead of setting it to `transparent`:

```
$(".sent").click(function() {
    $(".sent").css("background-color", "");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#e1e1e1");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
<p class='sent' id='abc'>abc</p>
<p class='sent' id='abb'>abb</p>
<p class='sent' id='acc'>acc</p>
```

**js**

```
$('.sent').one( 'click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('sent_clicked');  
});
```

or

```
$('.sent').one( 'click',function(){
    $('.sent').addClass('sent_clicked');  
});
```

**css**

```
.sent_clicked:hover{
background-color:#e1e1e1; 
}
```

Comment: This will not unset other `.sent` elements which seems to be what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out

```
$('.sent').css('background-color', 'transparent');
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!important` to your CSS would do the trick.

```
.sent:hover{
background-color:#e1e1e1 !important;
}
```

This is a quick and easy fix. You should avoid using `!important` in your CSS.

Comment: Whilst this would work, it is inherently bad practice. If you feel the need to use `!important` it usually means your CSS is bad.